# Convert iPhone App to iPad App (Just The Easy Part)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I make a basic View-Based application for iPhone in XCode 3.2, but when I switch the emulator to the iPad, the application gets "framed" (not sure what the right term is):

[iPhone App, Framed http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2652228/iphone-app-framed.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2652228/iphone-app-framed.png)

If I adjust the width of the View(s), it has no effect. I cannot adjust the width of the "Window" in Interface Builder (it's greyed out, and adding another Window to replace it gives me another Window instance in which the size is still grayed out). How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 4 then:

- Go to your Project Target Summary (Go to Project Navigator, Click on first horizontal project named row tab, then click on Targets and choose 'Summary' tab)
- In `Devices` drop down choose iPad (take a look at other options in settings below if you are interested)
- Now you can just run and see how you app will look on iPad.

Steps mentioned above are just a way to just scale your app to iPad resolution. But for a great app you might want to render app differently wrt device. You might want to code different ViewControllers for different devices.

You can read more on this here: [iOS Developer Library - Creating a Universal App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24)

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode, choose Project -> Upgrade Current Target for iPad... And read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW2) for details. It's all described in there step by step.

Comment: Thanks Ole, I'll check this out shortly and respond or vote here.

Comment: @Yar, "Upgrade Current Target for iPad" menu is disabled for projects of any template of cocos2d.